# Adding next and prev buttons to my image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to add a next and previous button to my image slider, but I'm not sure how to do so because I don't know how I would add them into a auto play slider. I have a basic structure, any help?

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="slider-container">
<div style="position: relative">
  <div class="slide"><img id="slide_1" src="images/slide_1.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="slide"><img id="slide_2" src="images/slide_2.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="slide"><img id="slide_3" src="images/slide_3.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="slide"><img id="slide_4" src="images/slide_4.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="slide"><img id="slide_5" src="images/slide_5.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="slide"><img id="slide_6" src="images/slide_6.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</div>
<img id="previous" src="images/prev.png">
<img id="next" src="images/next.png">
```

**My CSS:**

```
.slide-container 
{
display: block; 
}

.slide
{
top: 0;
width: 760px;
height: 420px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
transform: scale(0);
transition: all .7s 
}

.slide img 
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 6px;
border: 1px solid #95ca1a;
}
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function (){

    var count = $(".slide > img").length;
    var current = 1;
    var sliderNext = 2;

    $("img[id^='slide_']").fadeOut(0);
    $("#slide_" + current).fadeIn(300);
    var loop = setInterval(function() {
        $("#slide_" + current).fadeOut(300);
        $("#slide_" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        $('#next').click(function(){
        $("img[id^='slide_']" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        (sliderNext >= count) ? sliderNext = 1 : sliderNext++;
        (current >= count) ? current = 1 : current++;
    }, 3000)
})()
});
```

Comment: `(function (){})()` - this is not needed in the `$(document).ready()`. It is executed when it is parsed, not on domready.

Comment: Have you considered bootstrap carousel?http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code, one would be to move your current setInterval function into a next image function, then create a previous image function. On click you would want to re-initialise your timer then trigger the correct previous or next function.

Comment: Any idea how to re-initialize the timer to keep going with the auto play?

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle for your slider and I will help